# Flask, "GET" a single user from a list

Tags: javascript, python, list, flask, get

I'm currently learning Flask.

I've got a list of users that I've stored in my Flask file. I've successfully created a function that retrieves everyone on the list, but I'm having trouble getting it to only retrieve a single user in that list. I feel as if I'm pretty close, but I'm only getting the "404 missing user" message.

I want it to display the JSON of the chosen user on the list. e.g. going to /api/users/2 will get the user with an id of 2.

I'm almost certain it's a logic error with my get_single_user function.

Here's what I've done so far -

```
@app.route('/api/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_user_list():
page_number = int(request.args['page'])
user_slice = user_list[page_number * 6 - 6:page_number * 6]

return jsonify({"per_page": 6,
                "total": len(user_list),
                "total_pages": len(user_list) + 5 / 6,
                "data": user_slice})


@app.route('/api/users/<user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_single_user(user_id):

if len(user_id) == 0:
    return get_user_list()
found_user_int = -1
for user_position in range(0, len(user_list) - 1):
    if user_list[user_position]['id'] == user_position:
        found_user_int = user_position

if found_user_int >= 0:
    user = user_list[found_user_int]
    return jsonify(user)
else:
    return "missing user", 404


user_list = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
    "first_name": "George",
    "last_name": "Bluth",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "email": "emma.wong@reqres.in",
    "first_name": "Emma",
    "last_name": "Wong",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
}]
```

Here's the JavaScript to retrieve the data if it's any help -

```
function getASingleUser(userID){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","api/users/" + String(userID), true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        var objUser = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        renderSingleUser(objUser)
    }
    else {
        alert("Error " + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send()
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
    if user_list[user_position]['id'] == user_position:
        found_user_int = user_position
```

To:

```
    if user_list[user_position]['id'] == int(user_id):
        found_user_int = user_position
```

Also, unless you have a reason to store the user dicts as a list, it'd be a lot easier to store the entire thing as a dictionary with the user ID's as keys, then you can just do: `user_dict.get(int(user_id))`.

Lastly, wrap your API function in Try/Except so that the ajax call always gets a response. You can look into a standard for json responses, I can't remember them off the top of my head but it's usually like:

```
{'status':'ok', data: {'message':'text here'}}
```

The sooner you adopt that across all API calls, the better off you'll be down the road.